# Filter inside Aggregation for Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a query that tries to bucket the records by year field and then for each bucket, I want to

- Create a sub count (numerator) with a filter criteria and get cardinality (unique count) of custom_id
- Create a sub count (denominator) with a filter criteria and get cardinality (unique count) of custom_id
- Divide numerator and denominator

What I am not able to do is add the filter criteria for both numerator and denominator sub buckets.

Here is what my query looks like -

```
GET <index_name>/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": { . . <ABLE TO USE bool QUERY HERE>. . },
  "aggs": {
    "test": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "datetimefield",
        "interval": "year",
        "format": "yyyy"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "filter": { <UNABLE TO USE THE SAME bool QUERY here> },
        "denominator": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "custom_id.keyword"
          }
        },
        "numerator": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "custom_id.keyword"
          }
        },
        "division": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "denom": "denominator",
              "num": "numerator"
            },
            "script": "params.num / params.denom"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The reason why I need a filter block for numerator and denominator is because I have different set of criteria for both of them. Is it possible to do what I am trying to achieve here?

Comment: Do you get error on adding the filter or you don't get the expected result? Also it would be more clear if you add to the question the filter you are trying to apply.

Comment: You said you have a different filter for the numerator and the denominator, yet you only show a single filter. As @NishantSaini said, can you add your full query?